# reformat pdf names in a folder in windows through cmd line

Tags: windows, pdf, cmd

Problem: I have a folder of pdf files named like this "A Spaces - and - Caps.pdf"

I need to format them all like this "a_spaces_and_caps.pdf"

This Javascript does formats the file correctly:

```
var format_pdf_name = function(arr) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        result.push(arr[i].replace(/(\s+|-+|%+|(_){2,}|#+|&+)/g, '_').replace(/(_)+/g, '_').toLowerCase());
    }
    return result
}

var line = ["Job Aid - Performance Evaluations for Evaluators_2017-06-21.pdf"]

format_pdf_name(line)
```

How can I implement the above in a loop within my command line(windows cmd) to rename all the pdf files?

Comment: You could use `node.js` to call your javascript file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use PowerShell try this:

```
dir *.pdf | rename-item -newName {$_.Name.ToLower() -replace "\s+|-+|%+|(_){2,}|#+|&+", "_" -replace "_+", "_"}
```